# npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: node.js, npm

Устанавливаю NodeJs по этой ссылке: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-nodejs

Выполняю этот пункт: Выберите директорию, в которой будете решать задачи. Запустите в ней npm install node-static

Запускаю и вижу на экране следующее:

> npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND npm ERR! Cannot find module
>   'internal/fs'

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вообще похоже что нода криво стоит.

Comment: да, переустановил, пришлось помучиться - заработало)

Comment: Оформите ответом как ставили сначала и как переустанавливали? Может поможет кому)